# Print one table, two-column PHP associative array as three side-by-side, two-column tables

Tags: php, containers, html, html-table

I use the following to print a 15-row, two-column table from an associative arrray in PHP:

```
<table id="freq-table" class="table-list" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
<tbody>
    <?
    $rowCount = 0;
    foreach($word_frequency as $word => $frequency) if ($rowCount++ < 15) {?>
        <tr>
            <td><? echo $word; ?></td>
            <td<? echo $frequency; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?}?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

It works fine but takes up too much vertical space on the page. How can I format this into three side-by-side tables of five rows and two columns each with the first group having array items 1-5, the second group 6-10, and the last group 11-15? (refer to following illustration):

```
key1  value1  |  key6   value6   |  key11   value11
key2  value2  |  key7   value7   |  key12   value12
...
...
key5  value5  |  key10  value10  |  key15   value15
```

I've tried various table, div, container, and multiple loop experiments with very mixed (and unsuitable) results. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you need to use multiple tables? What about more columns?

Comment: More columns should work. I'm struggling with the looping logic in how to increment and identify what goes in each row/column of the three groups. Thank you for your prompt reply, Aiias. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some thing like that.

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<?php
    $rowCount = 0;
    foreach($word_frequency as $word => $frequency) if ($rowCount < 15) { ?>
   <?php if($rowCount % 5 == 0) {  ?>
     <td><table border=1>
   <?php } ?>                   
       <tr>
         <td><?php echo $word; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $frequency; ?></td>
       </tr>
       <?php if($rowCount % 5 == 4) {  ?>
     </table></td>
   <?php } ?>                   
<?php $rowCount++; } ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: kuldeep, this worked on first pass with a copy and paste. Amazing. Your use of: if($rowCount % 5 == 4) is very clever. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you can also use multiple columns to achieve this visual effect, you're going to probably want to format the data ahead of time to make the code of generating the table a little cleaner.

```
<?php
  // Format the array data so each row contains all of the columns needed
  $rows = array();
  $max_per_column = 5;
  $max_words = 15;
  $rows = array_pad($rows, $max_per_column, array());
  $count = 0;
  foreach ($word_frequency as $word => $frequency) {
    if ($count >= $max_words) {
      break;
    }
    array_push($rows[$count % $max_per_column], $word, $frequency);
    $count++;
  }
?>
<table id="freq-table" class="table-list" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
  <tbody>
    <?php
      foreach ($rows as $cols) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>', $cols) . '</td></tr>';
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Aiias, I like your pre-formatting idea. I tried it though with this code and it put everything on a single row--and the code didn't "know" to stop at 15 items... Thoughts?

Comment: @Andreas3204 - I wasn't aware you only wanted 15 items but had more than that to start with :). I have added a configurable amount of words (15 for now) to my answer. Oops! Forgot to increment the counter :D.

Comment: Aiias, this is brilliant solution. Your addition of the counters is flexible enough that it will allow me use this down the road when porting from desktop to smaller mobile displays. Thank you, kindly. Very nice work. :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to use a numeric key.  For example

```
 $word_frequency[0] = array();
 $word_frequency[0]['word'] = "some word";
 $word_frequency[0]['frequency'] = 10;
 ...
 $word_frequency[15] = array();
 $word_frequency[15]['word'] = "some other word";
 $word_frequency[15]['frequency'] = 14;
```

Once you have your array, you could repeat the loop as follows

```
<table id="freq-table" class="table-list" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
  <tbody>
<?
$rowCount = 0;
 for($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) { 
    $word[0] = $word_frequency[$i]["word"];
    $frequency[0] = $word_frequency[$i]["frequency"];
    $word[1] = $word_frequency[$i + 5]["word"];
    $frequency[1] = $word_frequency[$i + 5]["frequency"];
    $word[2] = $word_frequency[$i + 10]["word"];
    $frequency[2] = $word_frequency[$i + 10]["frequency"];
    ?>
     <tr>
    <?
    for($x = 0; $x <= 2; $x++ ){
 ?>

        <td><? echo $word[$x]; ?></td>
        <td<? echo $frequency[$x]; ?></td>

    <?
    }
    ?>
     </tr>

    <?
  }
    ?>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Every $i loop creates the row, while the $x loop creates the columns. This assumes, of course, that you have at least 15 items, that you're going to create only 5 rows and three columns of key/value pairs.

Comment: Robbert, thank you for your prompt reply. Thank you for taking the extra time to explain the logic. With your version I'm getting "Undefined offset: 0", "Undefined offset: 5", "Undefined offset: 15", etc. for each pass through the loops. (The incoming array is larger than 15 items but I'm only looking to display the first 15. Could that be an issue?)

Comment: Sounds like you haven't created a numeric index on your array.  Instead, you may still be using an associative array.

Comment: Yes [as posted in my question] it is an associative array. In re-reading your answer, it's clear: your code solution pertains to arrays with numeric keys. I missed that. I've bookmarked your code bcoz I actually have a use for it in the coming days. Thanks again, Robbert. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I were doing it, I'd probably use a ul with a css columns :D

http://davidwalsh.name/css-columns

However, that's not a very "programmerly" thing to do.

It might help that you don't have to go through the array in order.

If you look at what you have, there is a pattern to the indices:

i + 0x, i + 1x, i + 2x, ...

Where x is your number of items divided by the number of columns.

and you stop iterating when i = total / x

Sorry to be too tired to code this for you but the gist is this:

```
$myarray = [1 ... 15];
$columns = 3;

$arrayKeys = array_keys($myarray);
$total = count($array);
$x = floor $total  / $column;

for ($i = 0; $i > $x; $i += $x + 1 ){
  echo $arrayKeys[$i] . " - " . $myarray($arrayKeys[$i]);
  echo $arrayKeys[$i + $x] . " - " . $myarray($arrayKeys[$i + $x]);
  echo $arrayKeys[$i + ($x * 2) ] . " - " . $myarray($arrayKeys[$i + ($x * 2)]);
}
```

Or something like that... that's off the top of my head and I think it has some issues, but you should be able to beat that into something that works.

Comment: John, thank you for your time, consideration, and explanation. I've learned a lot with my failed attempts today--but not nearly as much as I've learned reading the answers. This goes a long, long way to helping me do this right. Thanks again.